# Turn off iPhone/Safari input element rounding

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile-safari, css-reset

My website renders well on the iPhone/Safari browser, with one exception: My text input fields have a weird rounded style which doesn't look good at all with the rest of my website.

Is there a way to instruct Safari (via CSS or metadata) not to round the input fields and render them rectangular as intended?

Comment: I wonder why _NO_ CSS reset seems to contain that super easy css rule. It's braindead.

Comment: I actually created a CSS reset based on eric meyer's css reset 2 with the added necessary css you find in the answer here. It is available on github: https://github.com/Jossnaz/JossiCssReset

Comment: Be careful with `-webkit-appearance: none;`, I think better to limit this condition to the scope of a specific input element. Otherwise it can to hide radio input elements if you have them on the page.

Answer (score 726, accepted):

On iOS 5 and later:

```css
input {
  border-radius: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

If you must only remove the rounded corners on iOS or otherwise for some reason cannot normalize rounded corners across platforms, use  `input { -webkit-border-radius: 0; }` property instead, which is still supported. Of course do note that Apple can choose to drop support for the prefixed property at any time, but considering their other platform-specific CSS features chances are they'll keep it around.

On legacy versions you had to set `-webkit-appearance: none` instead:

```css
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: As of iOS 5, this will only remove the inner shadow. Check Piyush's answer to remove the rounded corners as well.

Comment: @Jon Freeland: Thanks, I updated my answer (and voted his up).

Comment: `-webkit-appearance` actually has nothing to do with inner shadow and rounded corners. Don't use it just for that. http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance

Comment: @crmpicco: With or without `border-radius`?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It required `border-radius` to work on iOS 7.

Comment: @Rudie then what's the "right" way to remove Mobile Safari's rounded corners? `-webkit-appearance` seems to work fine.

Comment: "seems to work fine" is where developers create horrors. There are numerous exceptions you can't find that others will experience if you MISuse `appearance` for this, and suddenly forms are broken for some people, but they don't see that, because it doesn't show etc etc etc. If IOS wants rounded corners and shadows, let IOS users have them.

Comment: "If IOS wants rounded corners and shadows, let IOS users have them": That's completely unacceptable in my situation, and probably in most others' as well.

Comment: i have found out that by setting background-size: 0px; on ios7 in the webview in a phonegap app you can actually format the borders as you like.

Comment: !!you should not use this method, It makes checkbox seems to be unavailable Because of this, many of my site users doesn't proceed in payment agreement.!!

Comment: It's enough to *only* use `border-radius: 0;`. According to caniuse.com, browser share of Safari for iOS 3-4 is now less than 0.01%.

Comment: @Don McCurdy: Updated my answer.

Comment: For `<input type="search">` on iOS 10 I still needed `-webkit-appearance: none;`.

Comment: for iOS13 and bootstrap button with border, border-radius isn't enough either, -webkit-appearance: none; has to be set as well. Thanks for the hint

Comment: "If iOS wants...."  
@coredumperror just have the need to put here how right you are!

Comment: @DonMcCurdy is not enough for some cases, like input search. Needs to be with the appearance rule as well, Gabriel said

Comment: Here to confirm that, at least for `<input type="search">`, both `-webkit-appearance: none;` and an explicit `border-radius` style are still necessary in 2021 on iOS 14.4.

Answer (score 59):

`input -webkit-appearance: none;` alone does not work.

Try adding `-webkit-border-radius:0px;` in addition.

Comment: I did need to add the `-webkit-border-radius` attribute to `<input type="text">` to remove the rounded corners in iOS 5.

Comment: Don't need to add px after the 0

Answer (score 48):

It is the best way to remove the rounded in IOS.

```
textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"] {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     border-radius: 0;
}
```

**Note:** Please don't use this code for the Select Option. It will have problem on our select.

Comment: I've found that using `input[type]` seems to do the trick for all inputs.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer made radio button disappear on Chrome. This works:

```
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]) {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For me on iOS 5.1.1 on a iPhone 3GS I had to clear the styling of a search field and the set it to the style intended

```
input[type="search"] {-webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;}
```

Doing `-webkit-border-radius: 0;` alone did not clear the native styling. This was also for a webview on a native app.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the complete solution for Compass (SCSS):

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;  // remove shadow in iOS
  @include border-radius(0);  // remove border-radius in iOS
}
```

Comment: Just a note, the `@include border-radius(0);` mixin is only available if you have defined it yourself or are using the Compass framework, not just vanilla SASS.

Comment: Just a note, if you're using SCSS, you should probably be using autoprefixer too.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but only for the submit button. Needed to remove the inner shadow and rounded corners -

```
input[type="submit"] { -webkit-appearance:none; -webkit-border-radius:0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use normalize.css, that stylesheet will do something like `input[type="search"] { -webkit-appearance: textfield; }`.

This has a higher specificity than a single class selector like `.foo`, so be aware that you then can't do just `.my-field { -webkit-appearance: none; }`. If you have no better way to achieve the right specificity, this will help:

`.my-field { -webkit-appearance: none !important; }`

Answer (score 3):

I used a simple border-radius: 0; to remove the rounded corners for the text input types.

Answer (score 3):

Please Try This one:

Try Adding `input` Css like this:

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
       border-radius: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the buttons properly on Safari and other browsers, you'll need to give a specific style for the buttons in addition to setting webkit-appearance to none, e.g.:

```
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e4e4e4, #f7f7f7);
border: 1px solid #afafaf
```