# iPad default input border radius

Tags: html, css, ipad

The new iPad puts a default border radius on all my input fields.  How can I get rid of this default radius?

I verified that there is no border-radius property in the CSS and that there is no radius when  the MacBook Pro renders my site, but the new iPad does indeed have a radius on the text input fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure it's exclusive to the new iPad? Or might it be something pertaining to all iOS devices? I ask because the Safari browser in iOS devices does apply a specific styling to input elements.
You can, however, turn it off with this:

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Do that and `border-radius: 0` starts working just as you'd expect it to.

This has been answered here a few times before: [Turn off iPhone/Safari input element rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918707/turn-off-iphone-safari-input-element-rounding).

Comment: In my case, iPad New, border-radius works on it's own.

Comment: However, there is some annoying drop shadow, that the appearance attribute removes as well.

Comment: Yes it does that too. Instead of using none then, try using `textfield` . It's a valid value for that propery, however, I can't ensure it works as I myself am not seeing the rounded corners issue on my iPad without it.