# Can't get perfectly square submit button on iPhone. Also, button text is not centered

Tags: android, ios, css

I have a web-based mobile app which uses submit buttons styled with the following CSS class:

```
.submit_button_green input {
height: 26px;
width: 61px;
border: 0px solid;
font-size: 14px;
color: fff;
background-color: #00CC33;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -4px;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #333;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

On iPhone 4 (iOS7) corners are still slightly rounded corners and button text is positioned to the right (disappears off the right side of the button). On android devices, button is perfect.

Comment: Try setting border-radius:0

Comment: Thank for the help and the button is now perfectly square but the text is still off to the side. Any ideas there?

Comment: For that, try setting padding. e.g. padding: 5px 15px;

Comment: Actually, that slide the text a litter further to the right. I tried text-indent: -9px; and that centered the button on the iPhone but slid it off to the left on the android device.

Comment: heh, that's weird. I'm out of ideas mate, hope someone else comes for your rescue. Do a search meanwhile.

Comment: Got it! What worked on both was padding-top:4px padding-right:15px

Comment: eh? :D Weird it wouldn't pick shorthand for that.

Comment: that should be padding-top:4px padding-right:2px padding-left:2px and padding-bottom:15px. Thanks for getting on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918707/turn-off-iphone-safari-input-element-rounding) already. First set -webkit-appearance to none:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

And then set border-radius to 0:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: I had the first (look at the last line of the CSS) but was missing the border-radius part.  Thanks that squared up the button corners but the text is still off to the side.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Yes, I just added the comment to your reply above: For that, try setting padding. e.g. padding: 5px 15px;