# Select input field looking different in iphone 7 plus

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, media-queries

I am working on the **mobile view** of a [website](http://test.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/quality-productivity-database/) in which select input field is looking different in iphone 7 plus in comparison to other phones. I have created the sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mng5yk8L/5/embedded/result

The HTML code which is being used to create the select input field box is:

```
<p>
    <input type="text" name="filter_29" id="search-box-filter_29" value="">
</p>
```

**1st Screenshot:**
The screenshot of the **select input field boxes** which I am seeing in the **mobile view from my windows laptop** in chrome browser is:

[image]

**2nd Screenshot:**
The screenshot of the content (which I don't want) which I am seeing from my Iphone 7 plus phone is:

[image]

**Problem Statement:** 
I am wondering what changes I need to make in the css so that when I open the website in the mobile view from iphone 7 plus, it should look exactly the same as 1st screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off iPhone/Safari input element rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918707/turn-off-iphone-safari-input-element-rounding)

Answer (score 1):

```
select{-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

Adding that to any of the classes in your css should clear up any weird safari issues. I usually include it in my body selector of my CSS

Comment: @AriPalwary Thanks. I used the same now and it worked. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909283/website-footer-content-not-visible-in-iphone-7-plus/52909808#52909808). I am wondering if you can give me a pointer.

Comment: @john Absolutely What is the question?