# Search box acting strange and changing its border-radius on mobile - I can't reproduce the issue on desktop

Tags: css

My website has 404 page with search box built in. Everything looks great except for one small issue on mobile - desktop seems fine. I mean, when the dark mode is enabled, search box on 404 page starts acting strange, but only on mobile. At first it looks good, but when user clicks on it, its corners become way more rounded. After typing in at least two characters, corners transform again - this time to border-radius: 5px, which is fine. Does anyone know how to fix this? It has to have border-radius: 5px all the time. I feel like I've tried everything...

Here are the screenshots of particular "phases" in right order:

1. screenshot1
2. screenshot2
3. screenshot3

Here's a link to a random 404 page on my website: website.com - to reproduce the issue, turn dark mode on (via dedicated button in header) and enter the site on mobile - the browsers doesn't seem to be a problem - I've tested this on Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Seems like this is the same issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918707/turn-off-iphone-safari-input-element-rounding

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much... I would've never figured it out. So far this has been the strangest CSS Issue I've encountered.

Comment: That's the magic world of CSS :-). Success with your project, looks good.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you! :)