# CSS <input> border property, strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, forms

I am modifying the styling of my text field inputs for a contact form I have. My desired styling is a bottom border only, which seems to work in chrome but not on Safari for mobile, the whole border remains visible. See the below images for reference.

`Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (MacOS)`
[image]

Chrome works and looks fine.

`Safari iOS 14.6`
[image]

Here on my mobile, it is hard to see via the screenshot be some of the top corners of the border are visible, and the bottom border curves around.

`css`

```
export const TextField = styled.input`
   width: 100%;
   background: #131d32;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
   min-height: 35px;
   color: white;
   outline: 0;
   border-width: 0 0 2px;
   :focus {
       border-width: 0 0 1px;
   }`;
```

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918707/turn-off-iphone-safari-input-element-rounding

Comment: @sitharthan that worked - apologies if this is now a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Please set border-radius as 0;

```
export const TextField = styled.input`
   width: 100%;
   background: #131d32;
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
   min-height: 35px;
   color: white;
   outline: 0;
   border-width: 0 0 2px;
   border-radius: 0;
   :focus {
       border-width: 0 0 1px;
   }`;
```